# Any simple way to get which alternative got matched from a boost::regex match?

Tags: c++, regex, boost

For example, my regex expression is like `[0-9]*(Jan|Feb|Mar)[0-9]*`.

When my string to match is "23Jan23" then I knew that it has matched the first variant within the `(Jan|Feb|Mar)`.

And when my string to match is "23Feb14" then I knew that it has matched the second variant within the `(Jan|Feb|Mar)`.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you alter the regex pattern?

Comment: In other words, is the pattern user-defined, or can you re-write it to use `[0-9]*(?:(Jan)|(Feb)|(Mar))[0-9]*`? Then you could check which group matched easily with `m.str(n)`.

Comment: A regular expression is overkill for a straightforward text search like this.

Comment: I understand that it is an overkill if this is a question as-is. However, my real problem requires the regex in the first place, and the question I have asked is trying to see if I can avoid a second search.